# Spring Batch: Multithreaded step with AsyncItemProcessor doesn't run in parallel

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, threadpoolexecutor, itemprocessor

**TL;DR**

Given a file with a million reocrds where there is considerable amount of logic to be executed on each row in the file, what is the fastest way to read the file and finish applying the logic on each row. I used a multi-threaded step with file reader whose `read` method is `synchronized` to read the file and also used an `AsynItemProcessor` so that the records are processed in its own thread.

My expectation is that the `AsynItemProcessor` should start immediately as soon as it has a record from a reader to process. Each record should be processed in its own thread; however, this doesn't seem to be the case in my example below

---

I have a step in my Spring batch job that uses a `TaskExecutor` with 20 threads and commit interval of 10000 to read a file. I am also using an `AsycnItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter` since the data processing can at times take longer than the amount of time required to read a line from the file.

```
<step id="aggregationStep">
    <tasklet throttle-limit="20" task-executor="taskExecutor">
        <chunk reader="fileReader"
            processor="asyncProcessor" writer="asyncWriter"
            commit-interval="10000" />
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

Where :

1. `fileReader` is a class that extends `FlatFileItemReader` and the `read` method is ***`synchronized`*** and simply calls `super.read` within it.
2. `asyncProcessor` as nothing but a `AsyncItemProcessor` bean that is passed each row from the file and groups it by a key, and stores it into a singleton bean that holds a `Map<String,BigDecimal>`object. In other words, the processor is simply grouping the file data by a a few columns and storing this data in memory.
3. `asyncWriter` is nothing but an `AsyncItemWriter` that wraps a no operation `ItemWriter` within it. In other words, the job does not need to do any kind of writing since the processor itself is doing the aggregation and storing data in memory. (`Map`).
4. Note that the `AsynItemProcessor` has its on `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with `corePoolSize=10` and `maxPoolSize=20` and the `Step` has its own `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with a `corePoolSize=20` and `maxPoolSize=40`

With the above setup, my exepcation was that the reading and processing would happen in parallel. Something like :

1. FileReader reads a record from the file and passes it to the processor
2. `AsyncItemProcessor` performs aggregation. Since it is an `AsyncItemProcessor`, the thread that called the `process` method should ideally be free to do other work?
3. Finally, the `AsynItemWriter` would get the `Future` and extract the data but do nothing since the delegate is a no operation `ItemWriter`.

But when I added some logs, I am not seeing what I expected :

`2019-09-07 10:04:49 INFO  FileReader:45 - Finished reading 2500 records
2019-09-07 10:04:49 INFO  FileReader:45 - Finished reading 5000 records
2019-09-07 10:04:50 INFO  FileReader:45 - Finished reading 7501 records
2019-09-07 10:04:50 INFO  FileReader:45 - Finished reading 10000 records
2019-09-07 10:04:51 INFO  FileReader:45 - Finished reading 12500 records
2019-09-07 10:04:51 INFO  FileReader:45 - Finished reading 15000 records`

... more such lines are printed until entire file is read. Only after the file is read do I start seeing the processor start doing its work :

`2019-09-07 10:06:53 INFO  FileProcessor:83 - Finished processing 2500 records
2019-09-07 10:08:28 INFO  FileProcessor:83 - Finished processing 5000 records
2019-09-07 10:10:04 INFO  FileProcessor:83 - Finished processing 7500 records
2019-09-07 10:11:40 INFO  FileProcessor:83 - Finished processing 10000 records
2019-09-07 10:13:16 INFO  FileProcessor:83 - Finished processing 12500 records
2019-09-07 10:14:51 INFO  FileProcessor:83 - Finished processing 15000 records`

Bottom line : Why is the processor not kicking in until the file has been fully read? No matter what the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` parameters used for the `AsynItemProcessor` or for the entire `step`, the reading always completes first and only then the processing starts.

Answer (score 0):

This is how chunk oriented processing works. The step will read X items in a variable (where X is the commit-interval), then processing/writing are performed. You can see that in the [code of `ChunkOrientedTasklet`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/ChunkOrientedTasklet.java#L67-L76).

In a multi-thread step, each chunk will be processed by a thread.